# How do I echo this href in php?

Tags: php

```
<a href="<?php echo $row["snap"];">Snapchat</a>
```

Hey, so i'm building a basic program where it displays the users snapchat link from the database, I basically have everything finished(Data insertion, editing, displaying the link etc).

The only problem I have is that I can echo the snapchat for each row as php, but if the user doesnt enter their link it still displays the href tag, I basically just need it to just display the link only when the user enters the info. I have that all sorted out once again but I need a way to echo this in php.

Comment: `echo (empty($sanpchat)) ? 'N/A' : 'href'`

Comment: That is no valid PHP code, and you can simply check what `$row['snap']` contains and put a `if` around echoing the link. Can you show us what you've tried and explain what is not working yet?

Comment: @caltexs, did you try the answer here ?

Comment: `<a<?=@$row['snap']?" href='{$row['snap']}'":''?>>Snapchat</a>`, If you are going for short as possible, this might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
<a <?php echo (isset($row["snap"]) && !empty($row["snap"])) ? "href='".$row['snap']."'" : ""; ?> >Snapchat</a>
```

Comment: It would make more sense to hide the full link instead.

Comment: There's no need to check both `isset()` and `!empty()`. Simply checking for `!empty()` would suffice.

Comment: `empty` function checks weather an item is set `isset` and weather it has any value `!= ''`; By using isset with empty you are actually creating `if (isset && isset && row != '')`. Either use `empty` or `isset && != ''`, never both together. Basically - for speed use iset and value check, for simple reading - empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Solves the issues with `"` and `'`

```
<a <?php echo !empty($row['snap'])?'href="'.$row['snap'].'"' : ''; ?> >Snapchat</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the link only when user had a snapchat, then you need to put the if around the whole statement, otherwise you will get an empty link:

```
if (!empty($row["snap"])) {
    echo '<a href="'.$row["snap"].'">Snapchat</a>';
}
```

If you wish to display something else, in case there is no snapchat, just add `else` to it:

```
if (!empty($row["snap"])) {
    echo '<a href="'.$row["snap"].'">Snapchat</a>';
} else {
    // echo 'no snapchat';
}
```